# TapToZoom queries

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Has anyone analyzed the sample code for TapToZoom on iPhone.
The program performs 3 things
1. Double Tap, perform zoom
2. Two finger tap, perform zoom out.
and 3. Pinch zoom

I don't understand a small part of it.
The real image size is 1730 × 2430
So there is a scroll view in which an `UIImageView` of size 1730 × 2430 present. The image is set to Scale to Fit. i.e.
if the image is set to scale to fill the UIImageView which also has the 1730 × 2430, how does the image suddenly on launch fit the screen for the iPhone with reloution 320x460

The Image in the xib in its native size.
But when the app starts off, the image is not in its original size, but fits the scrollview content to fit.

How is this accomplished. I didn't find any piece of code that was doing the same in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Check this piece of code is present in `viewDidLoad` -

```
// calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
float minimumScale = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / [imageView frame].size.width;
[imageScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
[imageScrollView setZoomScale:minimumScale];
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this to calculate the scaling factor and zoom scale. My doubt is, if the image is set to scale to fill the UIImageView which also has the 1730 × 2430, how does the image suddenly on launch fit the screen for the iPhone with reloution 320x460.